# Using initialRoute tag in flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I'm experimenting with firebase on flutter. Found this *initialRoute* property in the documentation. I'm using it like this:

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new MaterialApp(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    "/login":(BuildContext context) => new SignIn(),
  },
  initialRoute: "/login",
  home: DefaultTabController(
    length: 4,
...
```

In this SignIn Activity is the GoogleLogin and I was initially using Navigator to switch between the two activities. I want to know what triggers will be used in the SignIn activity to switch between screens? Do I still use a Navigator?

In the SignIn activity I have a proceed button to perform this switch:

```
         new MaterialButton(onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(context,
 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> TabLayoutDemo.fromTabLayoutDemo(_auth, _googleSignIn)));
                  },
                    color: Colors.green,
                    splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    child: const Text("Proceed"),
                  ),
```

But what this does is launch the SignIn screen again after login completes.

Comment: Signin won't cause any navigation. You need to do navigation yourself using `Navigator` for example.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So does initialRoute just ensure that SignIn will be launched first? So after that do I need to use Navigator.pushReplacement()?

Comment: yes, or any of the other methods to pop/push routes. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please look at this again?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `Navigator` on your SignIn Activity to navigate between screens. However, you may need to check if there's a user already signed-in to skip the SignIn page. To check the currently logged in user, you can use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`.